# Cannot apply animation to parent frame from page WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a `page` within a `Frame`.What i am trying to do is to apply an storyboard/animation from the page to the parent `Frame`. Generally, from user controls, i used the following code to get the parent :

```
var parent = (Frame)this.Parent;
```

But if i use the same code in my page to get the parent frame and apply the animation :

```
private void Goback_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard;
sb = this.FindResource("HideMainframe");
var parent = (Frame)this.Parent;
Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, parent);
sb.Begin();
}
```

**Storyboard**

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="HideMainframe" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0" >
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CircleEase  EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

i get an exception : `No target was specified for   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'.`.On the web,i came to know about `VisualTreeHelper` class but before i'ld go for that, i want to know,why my code is not working ? Or to be specific,why can't i get the parent frame from the page within ?

Comment: What does your `HideMainFrame` storyboard look like?

Comment: I am currently using the `VisualTreeHelper` class but just wanna know whats wrong with my above code ?

Comment: Try putting the `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"` on the `DoubleAnimation` instead of the storyboard.

Comment: How will that even help ? Anyways, same result

Comment: @zackraiyan Any Storyboard attached property, like `Storyboard.TargetProperty` has to be set on an animation in the Storyboard, not the Storyboard itself. Read documentation please.

Comment: But the same storyboard works if it is triggered by a child within the parent...why's tht ?

Comment: When you do not explicitly set `Storyboard.Target` (or TargetName), the target is by default the element where the Storyboard is defined.

Comment: ow...i see....thanks for pointing out...anyway, i have two qs : Why didn't my above code work ? And if i keep using the storyboard in the same way(though it works),are there any consequences ?

Comment: `Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, parent);` set the Target property of the Storyboard, not the DoubleAnuimation. That's why *No target was specified for  'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'*

Comment: so u mean if i had set the target in the `DoubleAnimation`,it would've worked ?

Comment: Give it a try. As a note, `Storyboard sb = new Storyboard;` right before `sb = this.FindResource("HideMainframe");` is nonsense. Replace it by `var sb = this.FindResource("HideMainframe");`

Comment: But i tried that .. and same results...But now i am using the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the parent and surprisingly the same storyboard works perfect,keeping the target in the storyboard rather then the animation ...How's this working then ?

Comment: is the storyboard located in the Parent Frames XAML?

Comment: It's in the page's xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like Pages navigated in frames don't contain a "Parent" value, which is why the method you specified doesn't work, but walking the `VisualTreeHelper` does. What you are trying to achieve can be easily simplified by passing the `Frame` through the `Page` Constructor though.

Your Pages Code Behind

```
Frame f;
public Page1(Frame frame)
{
    f = frame;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Your button logic

```
private void Goback_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)this.TryFindResource("HideMainframe");
   Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, f);
   sb.Begin();
}
```

So when navigating the frame, you'll just pass it through.

```
myFrame.Navigate(new Page1(myFrame));
```